# Radius of convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (2 z^2)^n$, $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

What is the radius of convergence for the above series? My solution gives $R=0$, but it is wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a geometric series. It converges iff $|2z^2|<1$, i.e.
$$R = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since, $$\lim_{z\to \infty }\sqrt[n]{|(2z^2)^n|}=|2z^2|,$$
the radius is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}.$$